# Very high memory usage with simple Python loop

Tags: python, memory

I have the following code, which reads in a set of (small) observations, runs a cross-correlation calculation on them, and then saves some plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import astropy.units as u
from sunkit_image.time_lag import cross_correlation, get_lags, max_cross_correlation, time_lag

time=np.linspace(0,43200,num=int(43200/12))
timeu = time * u.s

for i in range(len(folders)):             # loop over all dates
    os.chdir('/Volumes/LaCie/timelags/RARs/'+folders[i])
    print(folders[i])
    for j in range(len(pairs)):           # iterates over every pair of data sets
        for x in range(36):               # sets up a sliding 2-hour window that shifts 20 min at a time
            ch_a = np.load('dc'+pairs[j][0]+'.npy',allow_pickle=True)[()][100*x:(100*x)+600,:,:] # read in only necessary data (but entire file is only ~6 Gb)
            ch_b = np.load('dc'+pairs[j][1]+'.npy',allow_pickle=True)[()][100*x:(100*x)+600,:,:] # read in only necessary data (but entire file is only ~6 Gb)
            
            ctime= timeu[100*x:(100*x)+600] # sets up the correct time array
            print('ctime range:',ctime[0],ctime[-1],len(ctime))
            
            max_cc_map = max_cross_correlation(ch_a, ch_b, ctime)
            tl_map = time_lag(ch_a, ch_b, ctime)
            del ch_a # trying to deal with memory issue
            del ch_b # trying to deal with memory issue
            
            plt.close('all') # making sure I don't just create endless open plots
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = fig.add_subplot()
            im = ax.imshow(np.flip(tl_map,axis=0), cmap="cubehelix", vmin=-6000, vmax=6000)
            cax = make_axes_locatable(ax).append_axes("right", size="5%", pad="10%")
            fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax,label=r"$\tau_{AB}$ [s]")
            plt.tight_layout()
            fig.savefig('timelag_'+pairs[j][0]+'_'+pairs[j][1]+'_'+str(x)+'.png',dpi=400)
            
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = fig.add_subplot()
            im = ax.imshow(np.flip(max_cc_map,axis=0), cmap="plasma",vmin=0,vmax=1)
            cax = make_axes_locatable(ax).append_axes("right", size="5%", pad="10%")
            fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax,label=r"Max Cross-correlation")
            plt.tight_layout()
            fig.savefig('maxcc_'+pairs[j][0]+'_'+pairs[j][1]+'_'+str(x)+'.png',dpi=400)
            
            fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
            values_tl, bins_tl, bars = plt.hist(np.ravel(np.asarray(tl_map)),bins=np.arange(-6000,6000,12000/50),log=True,label='Time Lags')

            values_masked, bins_masked, bars = plt.hist(np.ravel(np.asarray(tl_map)[np.where(np.asarray(max_cc_map) > 0.25)])
                                          ,bins=np.arange(-6000,6000,12000/50),log=True,label='Masked CC > 0.25')

            values_masked2, bins_masked2, bars = plt.hist(np.ravel(np.asarray(tl_map)[np.where(np.asarray(max_cc_map) > 0.5)])
                                          ,bins=np.arange(-6000,6000,12000/50),log=True,label='Masked CC > 0.5')
            values_masked3, bins_masked3, bars = plt.hist(np.ravel(np.asarray(tl_map)[np.where(np.asarray(max_cc_map) > 0.75)])
                                          ,bins=np.arange(-6000,6000,12000/50),log=True,label='Masked CC > 0.75')

            plt.ylabel('Pixel Occurrence')
            plt.legend()
            fig.savefig('hist_tl_cc_'+pairs[j][0]+'_'+pairs[j][1]+'_'+str(x)+'.png',dpi=400)
```

As noted in the comments, I've inserted a few lines to try to dump unnecessary data between iterations; I know a 3-deep `for` loop isn't the most efficient way to code, but the loop over the dates and channel pairs are very short -- almost all of the time/memory is spent in the innermost loop. The problem is that after a few minutes, the memory usage is oscillating between 30-55 GB. My Mac is becoming sluggish, and it's only at the beginning of the dataset. Is there something I'm missing here? Even if the entire files were being read in at the beginning instead of a subset, it's only ~ 12 Gb of data, and the code would crash if I was reading in the whole thing (i.e., it's definitely only reading in part of the raw data). I tried a `with` statement but that didn't take up less memory. Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Comment: This class of problem is what memory profilers are for. Don't ask people to guess when you can measure. (See https://github.com/bloomberg/memray as an example of a tool within the category).

Comment: I had no idea tools like this existed -- excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Per loop you create 3 figures but you never close them. After each `fig.savefig(...)`, you should close the figure with `plt.close(fig)`.

Comment: Actually, at the beginning of each new iteration I close the three previous plots with `plt.close('all')`, but I appreciate the tip!